# PHP for updating a MYSQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I am just starting to learn how to create backends for sites, since I already have a working knowledge of front-ends, but since I don't really understand making Wordpress themes, and it seems like a lot to learn for what it is truly worth, I am now asking, how do you go about two things.

1. How do you make a back-end page that will load the data from a table, and put it in an html table, then make each of those rows link to a page that...
2. Automatically loads the data specified in question 1 into an HTML form, and has a button that will update it?

If you need clarification on any part of any of my questions, just ask, I know it is probably a lot to ask, so even if you could just tell me where/how you learned to do this kind of high level coding, that would be great.

I really want to learn, not just copy and paste forever, so like I said, if you know and don't feel like explaining it, I'd be very interested in knowing where you learned it!

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/PHP-MySQL-Web-Development-Edition/dp/0672329166

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and in response to your "for what it is" remark above, if you are interested in using it, then maybe it is worth more than that. Go to wordpress documentation, it is extremely easy using have_posts get_post, but you would need to actually try before asking for help. We are no here to do things for you, we are here to help if you get stuck!

Comment: I have tried CodeAcademy, but even though it is a very good and fun learning environment, it is so basic that you can barely scratch the surface with it, and I have tried reading W3, but it too is pretty basic. Is this the book that you used to learn it all?

Comment: Also, thanks for telling me about the wordpress documentation, what is the link for that? And as I said above, I am mostly just asking for a resource to help me with those above questions, not asking for a free ride.

Comment: @user3057550 http://codex.wordpress.org/ and you want theme development, however if you want information on how to make a form that updates when you submit it, I do not know if that is in there or not, but it is for admin pages, just not regular pages.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you all learn about all of this stuff? Is there an online class or book I should use?

Comment: @vbo: If there is a problem with a post, please describe the problem in detail, instead of just posting "what have you tried". See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/152134) on whether "what have you tried" comments are acceptable and alternatives to "what have you tried". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "backend" table is called an SQL table, usually (and in the case of wordpress) it uses an SQL variant called MySQL.

To get data from an SQL table, you need to execute a **query** against it. For example:

```
SELECT `title`, `content` FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = 42;
```

This query will get (or **SELECT**) the `title` and `content` columns **FROM** the `posts` table, **WHERE** the `id` value of the row is equal to 42.

When a query is executed, PHP is returned with a resultset, usually in the form of an object or a resource, which can later be transferred into meaningful objects or arrays..

---

Each of the two steps you've asked about uses a different query. One to get all the entries, the other, based on the query parameter in the URL (`http://example.com/index.php?query=parameter`), queries a specific entry for more information to display it.

Comment: @user3057550: If this answer helped you, consider upvoting it (by clicking on the up arrow above the answer's score). If you found it to solve your problem, consider accepting it by clicking on the large green tick mark under the question's score. Good luck, and enjoy the site :)

Comment: It says that I need 15 reputation to up vote it, but if nobody else answers better soon then I'll just check it.